# How can I prevent data loss during refresh?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router

so I'm making a product detail page. So, everything works, when you click on the product, you are redirected to the appropriate page and the information is displayed. However, when you refresh the page, an error occurs and the product is lost. I understand that the url is lost during rendering and the error comes from this. I wanted to save that product in the state, but the same problem occurs again. How can I solve it

```js
import React, { useContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { GlobalState } from '../context/GlobalState'
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom'

const DetailPage = () => {


    const { data } = useContext(GlobalState)

    const { id } = useParams();
    const [a, setA] = useState({});

    useEffect(() => {
        getProductID();
    }, []);

    

    const getProductID = () => {
        let foundProduct = {};
        foundProduct = data.find((item) => {
            return item.id.toString() === id;
        });
        setA(foundProduct);
    };
    
    console.log(data);
    console.log(id);
    console.log(a);
    return (
        <>
            <div className="col-lg-3 p-3">
                <div className="card" style={{ width: '100%', height: "100%" }}>
                    <img src={a.image_url} className="card-img-top" alt="..." style={{ height: '300px', objectFit: "cover" }} />
                    <div className="card-body">
                        <h5 className="card-title">{a.name}</h5>
                        <p className="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default DetailPage


import React from 'react'
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom'

const SingleCard = ({ restaurant }) => {
    return (
        <>
            <div className="col-lg-3 p-3">
                <div className="card" style={{ width: '100%', height:"100%" }}>
                    <img src={restaurant.image_url} className="card-img-top" alt="..."  style={{height:'300px', objectFit:"cover"}}/>
                    <div className="card-body">
                        <h5 className="card-title">{restaurant.name}</h5>
                        <p className="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                        <NavLink to={`/product/${restaurant.id}`} className="btn btn-primary">More info</NavLink>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default SingleCard

import React from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom'
import Home from "../pages/Home"
import About from "../pages/About"
import Header from '../components/Header'
import { ContextProvider } from "../context/GlobalState"
import { useContext } from 'react'
import { ThemeContext, ThemeProvider } from '../context/ThemeContext'
import DetailPage from '../pages/DetailPage'
const AppRouter = () => {
    const { darkTheme, setDarkTheme, toggleTheme } = useContext(ThemeContext)
    return (
        <>
            <main className={darkTheme ? 'dark' : 'light'}>
                <ContextProvider>
                    <BrowserRouter>
                        <Header />
                        <Routes>
                            <Route path='/' element={<Home />} />
                            <Route path='/about' element={<About />} />
                            <Route path='/product/:id' element={<DetailPage />} />
                        </Routes>
                    </BrowserRouter>
                </ContextProvider>
            </main>
        </>
    )
}

export default AppRouter
```

Comment: Is there a reason not to use cookies?

Comment: cookies have maximum size is 4096 bytes so for data storage it not ideal

Comment: yoy can use sessionStorage to persist the data but keep remember to clear when not needed

Comment: I think there is no need for cookies for so little data, the only problem is updating which then the product data is lost, how can I save the state otherwise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is that your data is lost when you refresh the page.

You can fallow two approach to fix this issue

1. Keep updated data in session storage/local-storage and update context once we want. Use a similar approach in the context provider component.

   ```
   useEffect(() => {
        // Retrieve initial data from session storage
        const storedUsername = sessionStorage.getItem('username');

        // Set the initial data in the state
        if (storedUsername) {
          setUsername(storedUsername);
        }
      }, []);
   ```
2. Make another API call to get data in DetailPage. Your approach should like bellow.

```
const DetailPage = () => {


    const { data } = useContext(GlobalState)

    const { id } = useParams();
    const [a, setA] = useState({});

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!data) {
            // TO do this approach you should have a API in backend side returning product details for specific product id
            // Need to fetch data from API and update the context and data variable in this component
            // getProductID();
        } else {
            getProductID();
        }
    }, []);

    

    const getProductID = () => {
        let foundProduct = {};
        foundProduct = data.find((item) => {
            return item.id.toString() === id;
        });
        setA(foundProduct);
    };
    
    console.log(data);
    console.log(id);
    console.log(a);
    return (
        
            
                
                    
                    
                        {a.name}
                        Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.
                    
                
            
        
    )
}

export default DetailPage
```